# Apache2 mod_substitute not working in <Location>

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-proxy

I have a working Reverse Proxy that is active only on a specific Location in my site, in this case for example: `www.example.com/reverseproxy/site1` I am reverse proxying site1. I want to replace some part of the body of every page that is proxied so I tried to use mod_substitute, the problem is that I can't get it to work under `<Location /reverseproxy>`

This is my httpd (SSL is enabled):

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443> 

    ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
    RewriteEngine On

    ... Some rewrite rules
    RewriteRule /?reverseproxy/http(s*):/([^\/]*)/*(.*) "http$1://$2/$3" [P]
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPassReverse "/reverseproxy/http${ssl}://${page}" http${ssl}://${page} interpolate

    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE;
    ProxyHTMLInterp On
    ProxyHTMLExtended Off

    ...Some ProxyURLMap
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute "s|<body>|<body1>|"
</VirtualHost>
```

This substitute does work but it applies to all the pages and not only to `/reverseproxy`. When I try to put it in `<Location /reverseproxy>` it does not work, it just ignores it:

```
<Location /reverseproxy>
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s|<body>|<body1>|"
</Location>
```

### What I tried:

I tried adding

```
 RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
```

outside the `<Location>` tag but it didn't work

I tried then adding this

```
SetOutputFilter SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE
```

in the `<Location /reverseproxy>` tag but no luck

And as someone suggested tried with this filterchain

```
FilterDeclare filter
FilterProvider filter SUBSTITUTE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/html|"
FilterDeclare unpackGZIP
FilterProvider unpackGZIP INFLATE "resp('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip'"

<Location /reverseproxy>
FilterChain unpackGZIP filter DEFLATE
```

Everything else inside the Location works, it just seems to ignore the substitution.

Comment: You're not trying this in a .htaccess, are you?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille i have it in httpd conf

Comment: I believe there is a problem with your ProxyPassReverse, and as a consequence, your "<Location /reverseproxy>" doesn't capture the requests .   "The optional interpolate keyword, used together with ProxyPassInterpolateEnv, enables interpolation of environment variables specified using the format ${VARNAME}. Note that interpolation is not supported within the scheme portion of a URL."  =>  "http${ssl}"

Comment: @GerardH.Pille first of all thanks for your time, i believe you are right and my <Location /reverseproxy> doesn't capture requests. I tried removing the ${ssl} variable from the ProxyPassReverse (and on the ProxyPass above it), the page is still proxied but the Location tag still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Check out "RewriteRule /?reverseproxy/http(s*):/([^\/]*)/*(.*) "http$1://$2/$3" [P]" too,  which removes "reverseproxy" completely.  I must say this rule looks more suited for a forward proxy than a reverse proxy.   Anyway: your location should be based on what is in "$3".

Answer (score 4):

I'm glad to say that there is a way to get around the interpolation issue, at least with the substitution issue.

Lots of google results for interpolation with mod_substitute come here, so I figured I'd help. It is indeed possible to do something like this:

```
## These modules are required
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so

## Must be done in vhost directive
<VirtualHost:*:80>
PassEnv HOSTNAME_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME
Define SUBSTITUTE_STRING "s|http://hardcoded-url|http://${HOSTNAME_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME}|i"

<Location /my-path-here-wut-wut/>
        AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE my/mime-type-here
        Substitute "${SUBSTITUTE_STRING}"
</Location>


</VirtualHost>
```

When visiting `/my-path-here-wut-wut/` which returns HTML containing `http://hardcoded-url` it will be substituted to `http://<HOSTNAME_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME>`

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that was working for me, is:

```
AddOutputFilterByType INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE text/html
```

Source:

- https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T282613
- https://gitpull.it/T776